# Get brackets with stat_compare_means() and grouped columns

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I'm trying to plot some data in a grouped graph and then add the p-values of a statistical test for each group.

So far I manage to get the groups together and to calculate the statistical significance for each group/sub group. For some reason, `stat_compare_means()` only prints the all the p-values without a bracket. If there is more than one comparison per group (meaning: more than two sets of values within a group), all the p-values are printed on top of each other making them unreadable.

What I want to do is:

1. to have brackets showing which two sets of data was compared
2. to have the p-values of each comparison separately, so that they are readable.

Can anyone help me with that?

I already played around with various settings like `bracket.size` and so on, but I have not found any setting to enable brackets or the control for the vertical position of the texts.

About the data: I have several proteins (prot1, prot2, prot3) and I test them together with or without an activator (none, act1, act2) and then measure resulting enzymatic rates.

If I now run the following code:

```
library("dplyr")
library("tidyr")
library("ggplot2")
library("ggpubr")

rates <- tribble(
  ~subs, ~act, ~rate,
  "prot2", "act1", 2.478, 
  "prot2", "act1", 2.358,  
  "prot2", "act1", 2.384,  
  "prot2", "none", 0.748,  
  "prot2", "none", 1.194,  
  "prot2", "none", 0.930,  
  "prot1", "act1", 8.032,  
  "prot1", "act1", 8.728,  
  "prot1", "act1", 6.868,  
  "prot1", "act1", 7.568,
  "prot1", "act1", 8.244, 
  "prot1", "act2", 2.164,  
  "prot1", "act2", 2.146,  
  "prot1", "act2", 1.784,  
  "prot1", "none", 1.186,   
  "prot1", "none", 1.282,  
  "prot1", "none", 1.566,  
  "prot1", "none", 1.782, 
  "prot3", "none", 0.814, 
  "prot3", "none", 0.534,  
  "prot3", "none", 0.760,  
  "prot3", "act1", 1.086,  
  "prot3", "act1", 0.604,  
  "prot3", "act1", 0.848,  
)

# ensuring correct order of act
rates$act %<>% as.factor() %>% relevel("none")

# performing statistical test
rates %>%
  group_by(subs, act) %>% 
  compare_means(formula = rate ~ act, 
                data = ., 
                method = "t.test", 
                group.by = c("subs"), 
                ref.group = "none")

# plotting
complete(rates, subs, act) %>%
  group_by(subs, act) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = subs,
             y = rate,
             color = act,
             group = act
  ))  +
  geom_point(aes(group = act), 
             position = position_dodge(.9), 
             na.rm = TRUE) +
  stat_compare_means(method = "t.test", 
                     label = "p.format", 
                     na.rm = TRUE, bracket.size = 10)
```

I get this:

[image]

As you can see there are no brackets and for "prot1" the p-values are not readable as it both are printed on top of each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trying, I couldn't find a better solution than the following.
It still does not show the brackets, but the p-values of the comparison with the `ref.group` are shown.
So I decided to use facets (`facet_wrap(facet = vars(subs), ...)`) to have each protein shown separately, and add `ref.group = "none"` to `stat_compare_means` in order to have the values of each group compared to the reference group.
In order to have the formatted p-value readable in this case I also needed to add `label.y = c(9, 8.5)` to avoid overlaps of the labels.

```
library("dplyr")
library("tidyr")
library("ggplot2")
library("ggpubr")

rates <- tribble(
  ~subs, ~act, ~rate,
  "prot2", "act1", 2.478, 
  "prot2", "act1", 2.358,  
  "prot2", "act1", 2.384,  
  "prot2", "none", 0.748,  
  "prot2", "none", 1.194,  
  "prot2", "none", 0.930,  
  "prot1", "act1", 8.032,  
  "prot1", "act1", 8.728,  
  "prot1", "act1", 6.868,  
  "prot1", "act1", 7.568,
  "prot1", "act1", 8.244, 
  "prot1", "act2", 2.164,  
  "prot1", "act2", 2.146,  
  "prot1", "act2", 1.784,  
  "prot1", "none", 1.186,   
  "prot1", "none", 1.282,  
  "prot1", "none", 1.566,  
  "prot1", "none", 1.782, 
  "prot3", "none", 0.814, 
  "prot3", "none", 0.534,  
  "prot3", "none", 0.760,  
  "prot3", "act1", 1.086,  
  "prot3", "act1", 0.604,  
  "prot3", "act1", 0.848,  
)

# ensuring correct order of act
rates$act %<>% as.factor() %>% relevel("none")

# plotting
complete(rates, subs, act) 
rates %>%
  group_by(subs, act) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = act,
             y = rate,
             color = act,
             group = act
  ))  +
  facet_wrap(nrow = 1, facets = vars(subs)) +
  geom_point(aes(group = act), 
             position = position_dodge(.9), 
             na.rm = TRUE) +
  stat_compare_means(method = "t.test", 
                     ref.group = "none",
                     #comparisons = list(c("none", "act1"), c("none", "act2")),
                     method.args = list(formula = rate ~ act),
                     label = "p.format", 
                     label.y = c(9, 8.5), # this is only necessary if the labels are to wide and would overlap with each other.
                     na.rm = TRUE, bracket.size = 1)
```

Alternatively, if brackets are required, one could use the `comparisons` option of `stat_compare_means`:

```
complete(rates, subs, act) 
rates %>%
  group_by(subs, act) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = act,
             y = rate,
             color = act,
             group = act
  ))  +
  facet_wrap(nrow = 1, facets = vars(subs)) +
  geom_point(aes(group = act), 
             position = position_dodge(.9), 
             na.rm = TRUE) +
  stat_compare_means(method = "t.test", 
                     comparisons = list(c("none", "act1")),
                     method.args = list(formula = rate ~ act),
                     label = "p.format", 
                     na.rm = TRUE, bracket.size = 1) +
  stat_compare_means(method = "t.test", 
                     comparisons = list(c("none", "act2")),
                     method.args = list(formula = rate ~ act),
                     label = "p.format", 
                     label.y = c(9.5),
                     na.rm = TRUE, bracket.size = 1)
```

However, as one can see facets are still needed and `stat_compare_means` is needed twice. Once to compare "none" with "act1" and once to compare "none" with "act2" as for some reason only the first facet will receive brackets if both compare groups are set at once.